# Are there laptop brands with more than 1 year warranty?

Tags: laptop, warranty

I know costco adds one year to the manufacturer warranty but I'm wondering if there are manufacturers who offer more than 1 year warranty.

I've had a couple of laptops that broke a couple of months after the 1 year warranty expired and I think there should be manufacturers who think their laptops will work perfectly for more than a year. Do you know about one that does?

Comment: So far no one has come up with a manufacturer that includes more than 1 year warranty. Lenovo's extended warranty is cheaper, to me that means their hardware should be more reliable.

Comment: that's probably because it differs on different markets. here, I just looked it up ... HP and Toshiba have 3 year warr. on some "higher" models.

Comment: Move to Scandinavia ;-) 2 years warranty required by law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company I work for buys Thinkpads from Lenovo. I believe we get 3 year warranties on them. I'm sure they can offer you over a year, business or not.

Answer (score 0):

Acer lets you purchase a 2-year, and I *think* a 3-year warranty.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to Ignacio's answer, HP also offers 2 year warranty option purchase. As to the last question, the one I'm working on (laptop) currently is in its 5th year.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has multi year warranties.  Basically I think that almost ANY manufacturer will allow you to take out multi year warranties.

Also, lots of times your credit card may automatically extend warranties - something to look into - lots of people forget about that!